# get text content with loop of div with same class

Tags: javascript, html, loops

I have this code:

```html
<div class="user-fields-list"> 
  <div class="user-field">
      <div class="label">A</div> 
  </div>
   <div class="user-field">
      <div class="label">B</div> 
  </div>
   <div class="user-field">
      <div class="label">C</div> 
  </div>
   <div class="user-field">
      <div class="label">D</div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to get all the text content of the "label" divs.
How can I do that?

EDIT:
I need a loop because later I need to do some "if" conditions based on the text content of each div

Thanks all!

Comment: Could you show what you have done in order to solve it?

Comment: @MartínZaragoza I dont have done it yet... that's why I am asking

Comment: @Elle you should at least try to do it yourself. Show some effort. While people on stack overflow are happy to help, they are not here to write your code for you. Plus youll never learn if you dont try. - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Craicerjack yes true that...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll('.label')` to select all div with class `label` and loop over that to get its content:

```js
var targetDiv = document.querySelectorAll('.label');
for(var i=0; i<targetDiv.length;i++){
  if(targetDiv[i].textContent === "A"){
     targetDiv[i].style.background = 'red';
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="user-fields-list"> 
  <div class="user-field">
      <div class="label">A</div> 
  </div>
   <div class="user-field">
      <div class="label">B</div> 
  </div>
   <div class="user-field">
      <div class="label">C</div> 
  </div>
   <div class="user-field">
      <div class="label">D</div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! one question, How can I get the text value if I want to do a simple `if (labels === "A") {console.log("ok")}`

Comment: @Elle you can do `if(labels[i].textContent === "A") {console.log("ok")}`

Comment: @Elle you can tick mark the answer if it was helpful to you

Comment: ok thanks, last thing, how I can do something like this only if the loop find "A" `if(targetDiv[i].textContent === "A") {$(this).css("background-color", "red")}`

Comment: I would like to keep in touch with you. Thanks again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177649/discussion-between-ankit-agarwal-and-elle).

Answer (score 3):

You can use a query selector and forEach to get the textContent of each of the `div`s with a certain class.

```html
<div class="user-fields-list"> 
  <div class="user-field">
      <div class="label">A</div> 
  </div>
   <div class="user-field">
      <div class="label">B</div> 
  </div>
   <div class="user-field">
      <div class="label">C</div> 
  </div>
   <div class="user-field">
      <div class="label">D</div> 
  </div>
</div>
<script>
var text = "";
document.querySelectorAll(".label").forEach(div=>{
  text+=div.textContent;
});
console.log(text);
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

I would iterate through like this.
Initially get all the `.user-field` divs and after wards just forEach the nodes you received.

```js
let fieldsList = document.querySelectorAll('.user-fields-list .user-field');

fieldsList.forEach((currentValue, currentIndex) => {
   console.log(currentValue.innerText, currentIndex);
})
```

```html
<div class="user-fields-list"> 
  <div class="user-field">
      <div class="label">A</div> 
  </div>
   <div class="user-field">
      <div class="label">B</div> 
  </div>
   <div class="user-field">
      <div class="label">C</div> 
  </div>
   <div class="user-field">
      <div class="label">D</div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the class selector as following:

```js
var lab = document.getElementsByClassName("label");
for (var i = 0; i < lab.length; i++) {
  console.log(lab[i].innerHTML);
  //You can use innerHTML or textContent according to your need
}
```

```html
<div class="user-fields-list">
  <div class="user-field">
    <div class="label">A</div>
  </div>
  <div class="user-field">
    <div class="label">B</div>
  </div>
  <div class="user-field">
    <div class="label">C</div>
  </div>
  <div class="user-field">
    <div class="label">D</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="user-fields-list"> 
<?php foreach (range('A', 'Z') as $column){ ?>
  <div class="user-field">
      <div class="label"><?php echo $column; ?></div> 
  </div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats php. The question is tagged with JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

Simple for loop iteration through the webelement array and string concat should do the trick!

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('label');
var stringToConcat = "";

for (i = 0; i < elems.count; i++) { 
     stringToContact.concat(elems[i].text)
}

console.log(stringToConcat);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use   `document.getElementsByClassName('label');` to select all `div` with class `label`

```
   var items = document.getElementsByClassName('label');
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
           console.log(items[i].textContent);
```